# How to write file on SD-card with cordova.file plugin on a Kitkat device?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to write a file to the app directory on sd card with my samsung galaxy tab 4 device (Kitkat 4.4.2, Cordova 4.1.2, Cordova.file 1.3.2, Android 3.6.4).

How can I modify this [FileWriter example](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) to write in the app directory on SD-card instead of internal memory?

Also, if I try `console.log(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory);` the result is

> `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.name/files/" on the internal memory and not the Sd Card`

My SD-card is available by other apps like ES Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileWriter Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
            writer.truncate(11);
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
                writer.seek(4);
                writer.write(" different text");
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                    console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Write File</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) I would definitely get the [Cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) 2) use the Android [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)  API to get the path to your SD card.

Comment: I am using the Cordova file plugin

Comment: Do you have an answer now? @CharlesBlais

Comment: @CharlesBlais That is an issue that is reported. check it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10664